# Angular 7 Highchart Node.marker not working on page load

Tags: angular, highcharts, angular7, angular-highcharts

I am using Angular 7 with Highchart  at my dashboard which loads at first. When the page is loaded I want the marker to be of `radius:50` but when the page is loaded it does not set the **radius to 50**. When I click to other router link and come back then it works perfectly fine. I have replicate the problem in [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/addevent-highcharts-networkgraph?file=src/app/app.component.ts).

When the page is loaded at first it won't displays correctly when I uncomment the `debugger` in `addColours()` it works as expected. I know I am doing something wrong that some part of the code is executed prior to the formation of graph or some of the file is getting delayed in loading.

I have tried modifying like this as well

```
let highchart: any = Highcharts;
Highcharts.addEvent(Highcharts.Series, 'afterSetOptions', function (e: any) {
  var colors = Highcharts.getOptions().colors, i = 0, nodes = {};
  if (this instanceof highchart.seriesTypes.networkgraph &&
    e.options.id === 'network-budget') {
      ---- doing my stuff
    }
```

Comment: I see that you are using not official Highcharts Angular wrapper. Try to reproduce your case using the officially supported wrapper: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular

Comment: Which one is the official `highcharts-angular` or `angular-highcharts`

Comment: using `highchart-angular' too haing same problem ..... here I have reproduce it in stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/networkgraph-highchart-angular?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: I checked both demos, and it seems that everything is working correctly with the `highcharts-angular` - the markers have the correct size after the page has been loaded. According to your previous question - `highcharts-angular` is the only official wrapper for the Angular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`chartCallback` fires when the chart is already fully rendered and ready to start the initial animation. Your custom logic launches when `afterSetOptions` is triggered. In order to make it happen the series has to be updated. So, I added this line to force the update:

```
chart.series[0].update({})
```

[Live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/networkgraph-highchart-angular-mleuzu?file=src/app/app.component.ts)